# Kendo ui datagrid - Insert new row by fetching value from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, datagrid, kendo-grid

- I have a text box when I copy the file path which is present in my machine in the text box and hit save. I need to save that  file in the kendo grid.
- can you guys tell me how to do it.
- got the grid and the text box.
- but not sure how to save the file in the grid.
- providing my code in the fiddle.

Here is my demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/6ozr348y/1/

```or-tag-here
$(document).ready(function() {
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
        data: [
            { FileName: 'need to get the value from the text box', LastName: 'LastName'},
            { FileName: 'need to get the value from the text box', LastName: 'LastName'},
            { FileName: 'need to get the value from the text box', LastName: 'LastName'},
            { FileName: 'need to get the value from the text box', LastName: 'LastName'},
            { FileName: 'need to get the value from the text box', LastName: 'LastName'}],
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        FileName: { type: "string" },
                        LastName: { type: "string" }                    }
                }
            },
            sort: {
                field: "FileName",
                dir: "asc"
            },
            pageSize: 10
        },
        height: 500,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: true,
        filterable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            {
                field: "FileName",
                title: "File Name"
            },
            {
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name"
            }
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");

    grid.tbody.parents(".k-grid-content").eq(0).kendoScroller({ useOnDesktop: false });
});
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, and I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve, but I think it's impossible to grab a file from the local file system using a string path in javascript due to security reasons.

Comment: @SamJudge is there anyway we can achieve it??

Comment: It's possible, but not purely in javascript, and probably not the way you want it to be done. Browsers typically only allow file uploads using a `<input type="file">` tag, and even then some browsers (chrome) hide the file path from the website. You would need to submit your file as part of a form, allowing the actual browser to pass along the file data to a server side script and store it on your server, then reload the page, and grab the data of that uploaded file as an AJAX request (Or compose the data when creating the page using a server side script).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/xerj4g8e/). Below is the code:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
        data: [
            { FileName: 'need to get the value from the text box', LastName: 'LastName'},
            { FileName: 'need to get the value from the text box', LastName: 'LastName'},
            { FileName: 'need to get the value from the text box', LastName: 'LastName'},
            { FileName: 'need to get the value from the text box', LastName: 'LastName'},
            { FileName: 'need to get the value from the text box', LastName: 'LastName'}],
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        FileName: { type: "string" },
                        LastName: { type: "string" }                    }
                }
            },
            sort: {
                field: "FileName",
                dir: "asc"
            },
            pageSize: 10
        },
        height: 500,
        scrollable: true,
        //editable: true,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: true,
        filterable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            {
                field: "FileName",
                title: "File Name"
            },
            {
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name"
            }
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");

    //grid.tbody.parents(".k-grid-content").eq(0).kendoScroller({ useOnDesktop: false });

    $('#save').click(function(){
        var fname = $('#fname').val();
        //alert(fname);
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
        var total = dataSource.data().length;
        dataSource.insert(total, {FileName:fname, LastName: 'Last Name'});
        //grid.addRow({FileName: fname});
        alert('New row added !!');
        $('#fname').val('')
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<h3>Enter filename in textbox and hit Save button. The new row with filename will be added to the grid</h3>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter filename">
<button type="button" id="save">save</button>


<br>
<br>
<br>

<div id="grid"></div>
```